# Select all column and distinct by one specific column

Tags: sql, hive

I used HIVE for query,I like to query all columns and based on distinct specific one column.

for example I have table a;

```
StudentID
StudentName,
StudentBirsthDay,
StudentPassport;
StudentAge;
StudentRegisted;
....
....
```

I want query all students with unique StudentID,

select *,distinct(StudentID) from a;

how should i write the query?

Thanks alot

Comment: please indicate the rdbms you are using (mysql or hive?) and please explain the problem a bit more clearly, with some example data.

Comment: If there is more then one row with the same studentid, the which of them should be returned?

Comment: Hi, I'm used Hive, i like to distinct my studentID and print all the columns.

Answer (score 3):

Why would `StudentId` be duplicated?  That sounds like a problem in your application.

To get the unique `StudentId`s:

```
select StudentId
from t
group by StudentId
having count(*) = 1;
```

You can get all the columns in different ways, but one way that will work in all databases is a `join`:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select StudentId
      from t
      group by StudentId
      having count(*) = 1
     ) tt
     on t.StudentId = tt.StudentId;
```

EDIT:

In Hive, you would use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by StudentId) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

Note:  If you wanted *one* row for all `StudentId`s, then you would use `row_number()` instead of `count(*)`.

Comment: I need query all the columns, but in your case there can only show the one StudentID column

Comment: StudentID could be duplicated, because all data collect from logs.

Comment: @user2953788 . . . The second query gets all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

query write like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...
    FROM table_name;
```

**example:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT StudentID FROM a;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got your point
select *,distinct(StudentID) from a; is not gonna work in this case you can use group by on that column that will work as distinct in this scenerio
select * from a group_by StudentID;
select *